# Custom Taxonomy terms aren't getting referenced or saved in Quick Edit or Bulk Edit, only on Single product page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, save-post

I am using Woocommerce, Elementor, ACF Custom Fields and CPT for Custom Post types.

I have a custom taxonomy called 'biographies' which has some associated custom fields (first name, last name, birth year, death year).

I have created a simple shortcode that outputs the full name (i.e. First name + Last name). This works fine to echo this info in a shortcode block. This is the shortcode code:

```php
        add_shortcode( 'just_bio_name', 'show_just_bio_name' );
    function show_just_bio_name() {
        global $post;
        $html  = '';

    if (get_field('bio_tax', $post_id)) {
    $taxonomy = 'biographies';
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'biographies' );
    if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
                   if (get_field('bio_first_name', $term) && get_field('bio_last_name', $term)) {
                        $bio_name = get_field('bio_first_name', $term) . ' ' . get_field('bio_last_name', $term);
                } else {
                  $bio_name = $term->name;
                }
      $html .= $bio_name;
        }
    }
    } 
    return $html;
}
```

In addition, I'm using the save_post function to update the product slug on save. I am using do_shortcode to add the shortcode output to the data saved in that function. Basically I'm adding a custom name from a custom taxonomy to the product slug. Here is the code for the save_post function:

```
function slug_save_post_callback( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {

global $pagenow;

// allow 'publish', 'draft', 'future'

    if((isset($post) && $post->post_type != 'product') || $post->post_status == 'auto-draft')
    {
      return;
    }

$productTitle = $post->post_title;

if (get_field('bio_tax', $post_ID)) {
    $bioName = get_field('bio_tax', $post_ID);
    $slugBioName = sanitize_title( do_shortcode('[just_bio_name]') );
    $slugBioName = '-'.$slugBioName;
} else {
    $bioName = "";
    $slugBioName = "";
}

if ($acfFullTitle) {
$slugTitle = substr($productTitle, 0, 50);
    $slugTitle = sanitize_title($slugTitle);
}

$new_slug = $slugTitle.$slugBioName;

// unhook this function to prevent infinite looping
remove_action( 'save_post', 'slug_save_post_callback', 20, 3 );

// update the post slug (WP handles unique post slug)
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $post_ID,
        'post_name' => $new_slug,
        'post_title' => $productTitle
        ));
        // re-hook this function
        add_action( 'save_post', 'slug_save_post_callback', 20, 3 );
    }
    add_action( 'save_post', 'slug_save_post_callback', 20, 3 );
```

This saves perfectly on the Single product page but the data from the shortcode/taxonomy doesn't work when using the quick edit or bulk edit functions on the product grid pages, where it saves without the name addition. If I put some random string in the shortcode, then this works in Quick Edit so its not the shortcode itself, its something to do with how I'm getting the taxonomy terms - they work for single product page and not for quick edit. I've narrowed it down to that this line doesn't retrieve anything: `if (get_field('bio_tax', $post_id))  {` so I'm suspecting it might have to do with me referencing the wrong post ID value (I tried `Get_the_ID()` but it didn't change anything). Help in solving this would be much appreciated!